# Python. Calling a function that applies a mutation to an object. Mutation does not apply in the calling context

Tags: python, python-3.x, mutable

I have a class that has a field called tour.
In that class I also have a function that removes a location from a tour.

## remove inside of the class Tour

```
def remove(self,location, to_print=False):
    

    location.tour_id = None
    index_to_delete = None
    
    if to_print:
        print("before removee" +str(len(self.tour_locations)))
  
    
    for i in range(0,len(self.tour_locations)):
        if self.tour_locations[i].id_ == location.id_:
     
            index_to_delete = i
            
    if index_to_delete is None:
        print("element not found")
        return
    else:
        del self.tour_locations[index_to_delete]


         
    if to_print:
        print("after removee" +str(len(self.tour_locations)))
```

Now i call this function from somewhere else (NOT IN TOUR CLASS):

## apply

```
def apply(self):

    tour_location = self.extra_information['tour_location']
    position = self.extra_information['position']
    tour= self.extra_information['tour']  
    origin_tour = self.solution.get_tour_by_id(tour_location.tour_id)
    destination_tour = self.solution.get_tour_by_id(tour.id_)
    
    if to_print:
        print("origin_tour before  " + str(origin_tour))
        print("dstination tour before" + str(destination_tour))
        
    origin_tour.remove(tour_location, to_print=to_print)
    destination_tour.insert_at(tour_location, position)
    
   
    if to_print:
        print("origin_tour after  " + str(origin_tour))
        print("dstination tour after" + str(destination_tour))
    return self.solution
```

The print line in the class is printing the tour consistent with a location removal.

The print line ("after") in the apply function is showing the tour without any modifications.

How is this happening?

Comment: update: if I replace destination_tour.insert_at(tour_location, position) with destination_tour.tour_locations.insert(position, tour_location_copy) the destination_tour is mutated.
Isn't the previous line doing the same thing ?

Comment: if i return self in the tour class,
printing self in the tour class and printing it upon returning gives different values!

Answer (score 0):

You should not use `del` to remove an item from a list. Use `list.pop(index)` or `list.remove(value)` instead. In your case you should use `list.pop(index)` beacuse you want to remove an item at a specific index from the list. [Documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.8/tutorial/datastructures.html)

Comment: same problem persists

Comment: Why should one not use `del` to remove an item from a list by index?